# How do I overlay one image at a specific loction on top of another image

Tags: html, css

I need to create web page where I have base icon/image, and then I want to lay over the the top either colored dots and/or another smaller icon a specific place on the base image. What is the best way to do that? I would probably need to do this in Javasricpt as far as the proper location of the dots/image.
Here it was I started to play around with
Thanks!

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <img src="a.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
  <img src="b.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 70px;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: are these images always going to be the same sizes?

Comment: Don't mix html with css. Just don't.

Comment: Set a container for each of your images, so you get a controlled area to set your images... use the zindex of the elements to take care of the positioning ans of course the top image should be "transparent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add onto pranesh answer's the easiest way to position the overlayed images properly is to have both image the same size so then when you set both of them at :
top: 0, left: 0
they will show up correctly.

Another option would be to use canvases.

Comment: The top image needs to scaled to a smaller size

Comment: Then make the underlying image the size of the scaled down image or make them both the same original size and scale both down.

Answer (score -1):

Look into Z-indexing with positioning.